# Can I Adjust Thickness of Spheres and Cylinders to Make Objects Printable in 3D?

Tags: graphics3d, chemistry, 3d-printing

I have a design of a crystal structure using  **Sphere**  and **Cylinder** in Mathematica. I then exported the result as an STL file and tried to print it.  I was told that the objects were "too thin,"  that Mathematica didn't produce a solid sphere or cylinder, but just a shell.  This made the connections holding the structure together to be too fragile.  At least, this is what the technician running the printer said...

I have seen how to make **Plot3D** surface thicker using the **Thickness[]** directive to **PlotStyle** but this doesn't work (I think) for **Sphere** and **Cylinder**.

Has anyone tried to print molecules or crystal structures using Mathematica? If so, was this an issue?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: i would suggest a different route for your application, starting from a PRB or CIF crystallography file, which you should be able to export from Mathematica, as described by this recent article ([Scalfani, Vaid, *Journal of Chemical Education*](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed400887t?mobileUi=0)). The authors propose viable choices for such problems as sphere size, bond thickness, etc.

Comment: For cylinders, I addressed `STL` export in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51573/245). In fact, it's many cylinders combined into something like a sphere...

Answer (score 1):

In case the 3D printer does indeed require triangles that are arranged more like tetrahedra to give the surface a thickness, you can achieve that using [`RegionDifference`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDifference.html), where the construction of a spherical shell is described as an example:

```
shell = RegionDifference[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 2], Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1]];

dg = DiscretizeRegion[shell];
pts = MeshCoordinates[dg];
polys = MeshCells[dg, 2];
g = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Thick], GraphicsComplex[pts, polys]}]
```

[image: shell]

This automatic triangulation of the shell certainly doesn't look very clean. But it now should have something you could call *thickness* because it's a shell.

Comment: Can that be extended to shells with a given thickness?

Comment: @YvesKlett I think you can probably work something out using `RegionDifference`. But I actually don't know enough about 3D printing to pursue this approach further, until someone explains to me whether this answer is going in the right direction or not... Perhaps I took the reference to `Thickness[]` in the question too seriously. But according to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39879/245), it does seem to matter.

Comment: @YvesKlett Oh, I think I understand now. `Thickness[]` in the question was in fact misleading, but I do need to use `RegionDifference` to get volumes of the required type. I'll see if I can update the answer...

Comment: Super, that should be most useful!

Comment: @YvesKlett And I shouldn't have said `Thickness[]` is misleading, because there's actually [this Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37684/245) where `PlotStyle -> Thickness[.1]` was used to turn contour surfaces into volumes. In principle, that could also be done here, but my goal was to *not* abandon `Sphere` and `Cylinder` outright.

Comment: I also only thought of the EPS `Thickness`, some way to use arbitrary primitives would be much preferrable.