# How to get rid of clipping artifacts?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, rendering

The following is a MWE extracted from a more complex graphic.

```
vertex = {8 Sqrt[2/((5 - Sqrt[5]) (10 + 2 Sqrt[5]))], 0, 8/
  Sqrt[(10 - 2 Sqrt[5]) (10 + 2 Sqrt[5])]}; 
example[r_] := 
 Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3, GrayLevel[0.8]], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r], 
    GrayLevel[0.2], Opacity[1], 
    Style[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 3], 
     ClipPlanes -> 
      Hyperplane[vertex, Cos[30 Degree]*3*Normalize[vertex]]]}, 
   Boxed -> False], Lighting -> "Neutral", 
  ViewPoint -> {1.7, -2.7, 1}, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, 
  ImageSize -> {1000, Automatic}]

Export["ex1.png", example[3]]
Export["ex2.png", example[3.001]]
```

[image: First example]

[image: Second example]

The second example is a bit better than the first one, but both show artifacts that I'd like to get rid of.  (To clarify what I'm talking about: In both cases, the boundary of the spherical cap is clearly some $n$-gon and not a circle.  And `Example[2.999]` would have the same effect.)

How can I improve this?  Is there a way to increase the mesh granularity of the sphere?  Or is there a better way to create the spherical cap?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to increase the smoothness of a cylinder?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51565/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-smoothness-of-a-cylinder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `Method -> {"SpherePoints" -> 300}`. With this option there are no artifacts:

```
example[r_] := 
 Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3, GrayLevel[0.8]], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r], GrayLevel[0.2], 
    Opacity[1], 
    Style[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 3], 
     ClipPlanes -> Hyperplane[vertex, Cos[30 Degree]*3*Normalize[vertex]]]}, 
   Boxed -> False, Method -> {"SpherePoints" -> 300}], Lighting -> "Neutral", 
  ViewPoint -> {1.7, -2.7, 1}, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> {1000, Automatic}]
```

Checked with version 12.0 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.  I'd say this is almost impossible to find in the Mathematica documentation unless you already know the answer...