# Why are my plots displaying behind the axes?

Tags: plotting

I need to create graphs with light gray axes and black lines. All of my plots display behind the axes. How can I make the plots display over the axes?

```
Plot[2 x - 2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},    
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[2]], ImageSize -> 300, 
    AxesStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[.8, .8, .8], AbsoluteThickness[2]], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/106) post by [Verbeia](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/8/verbeia) might also be of interest.

Answer (score 57):

The cure is <strike>undocumented, unfortunately</strike> now documented, as of version 10. Try adding `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}`, like so:

```
Plot[2 x - 2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[2]], ImageSize -> 300, 
     AxesStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[.8, .8, .8], AbsoluteThickness[2]], 
     AspectRatio -> 1, Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```

[image: plot with axes in front]

There is also a corresponding `"FrameInFront"` option for frames, and `"GridLinesInFront"` for grid lines.

Comment: In version 10 it is documented on the [`Graphics` documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) under "Details and options".

Comment: Nice to know that it's finally documented. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if something similar exist for the tick labels. It seems there's no reference for that in the documentation.

Answer (score 13):

There can be another solution. `FullGraphics` can convert the axes to graphics primitives, then you can manipulate the order of layers by hand:

```
FullGraphics[
Plot[2 x - 2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[2]], 
ImageSize -> 300, 
AxesStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[.8, .8, .8], AbsoluteThickness[2]],
AspectRatio -> 1]] /. Graphics[x_] :> Graphics[Reverse[x]]
```

---

**Comment from rcollyer**:

> `FullGraphics` is spotty, so take care in its use.

Comment: AxisInFront is simple and works well. I'll give that a good testing for my project. Good to know there is another option, especially for my own knowledge. Thank you!

Comment: @lvames Glad I can help.

Comment: @lvames `FullGraphics` is spotty, so take care in its use.

Answer (score 4):

I found this useful, though a little ugly.

```
Overlay[{
 ListPlot[{0,0},PlotRange->{{-10,10},{-10,10}}, ImageSize->300, AspectRatio->1,
          AxesStyle->Directive[RGBColor[.8,.8,.8], AbsoluteThickness[2]]],
 Plot[2 x-2,{x,-10,10}, PlotRange->{{-10,10},{-10,10}}, Axes->False, AspectRatio->1,      
      PlotStyle->Directive[Black,AbsoluteThickness[2]],ImageSize->300]
}]
```

But you cannot directly save the image, you can select the cell and `save selection as` image.

[image]

`Reverse` the list in `Overlay` will get the result where black line behind the axes.