# X-axis obscuring a vector that lies along it

Tags: graphics, vector

I am having the following problem. I am playing with `Manipulate` and I would like to draw a vector overlapping an axis (x-component of a vector), and I would like the vector to be blue. But the axis is in the foreground, therefore I don't see the color. How can I bring the arrow in foreground? Anyone have encountered this? I can post code if it helps.

Comment: There is `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}` but if you use `Epilog` then it will be on top automatically `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 Epilog -> {Blue, Thickness@.02, Arrow[{{.1, 0}, {.5, 0}}]}]`

Comment: Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False} worked. If you post it as an answer I will accept it as such. Fantastic. Thanks.

Comment: It's almost a duplicate of [Why are my plots displaying behind the axes?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26917/5478) but if you need it works only for arrow then `Epilog` is a second way. But since you've chosen `Method` then I will mark it as duplicate.

Comment: @Kuba. No, I don't think 5770 is better.

Comment: @m_goldberg Ok :P and thanks for editing my posts. I have to read more in english I think :(