# Show graphics content in front of frame

Tags: graphics

Consider some graphics which spill over the plot range, like these:

```
Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.1, .9}, {-1.1, 1.1}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 20, FrameStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Can I make the graphics be drawn in front of the frame without drawing the frame manually?  Is there a possibly undocumented option for this (maybe a `Graphics` `Method` option)?

Comment: I realize that this may be considered unreasonable, but I have some requirements to follow.

Comment: I voted to close, since the method option @kguler used is actually documented now...

Comment: @BrettChampion But it wasn't ever used in this site :)

Comment: @BrettChampion I'd take objection with the "simple to find" bit :P  Anyway, closed or not, I got my answer, which is what I wanted.  Being on the receiving end (and also: having had to learn new technologies recently and experiencing the newbie perspective again), I do think we have overused this closed reason here.  I am definitely guilty of that.

Comment: @BrettChampion v10 has a lot of Method options newly documented, which is really great.  It has been one of the biggest complaint from users that these were not properly documented before.

Comment: [Related question also using these options](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32231/12)

Comment: I don't agree with closing this question just because the latest version includes documentation that answers the question. Or was @Brett_Champion just kidding?

Comment: @Szabolcs I just looked that question up. :-)  [Early-to-mid-September -- must be time for a "InFront" question again, I guess..)

Comment: @rhermans Consider it a way of encouraging people to re-chek the docs, even if they think they know what is (or isn't) in them.  And besides, how often do you get a chance to cast a close vote on a 50+K user? :-)

Comment: Ok, so you are joking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are my plots displaying behind the axes?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26917/why-are-my-plots-displaying-behind-the-axes)

Comment: @Szabolcs The close reason when I chose it used "easy to find", rather than "simple to find".  And you'd already mentioned 'a `Graphics` `Method` option', so you were clearly thinking along the right path...  But I agree that we do overuse this reason for closing. Anything is easy to find, if you already know where it is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A few wild guesses (trying to mimic the `"GridLinesInFront"` suboption of the option `Method`) gave the following:

```
Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1.1, .9}, {-1.1, 1.1}}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 20, FrameStyle -> Thick, 
  Method -> {"FrameInFront" -> False}]
```

[image]

This option is [documented (see under Details and Options)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) since version 10.