# Changing BarLegend border style

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, legending

I want all the lines in my plot to be a consistent style, let's say thick and black for the purpose of this question.

```
ContourPlot[y - x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black, Opacity[1]], 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black],
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic]]
```

[image]

However, the border of the legend bar is thin and grey. How do I change its style to match? I couldn't find any relevant options in the [`BarLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html) documentation.

Comment: I'm really glad you asked this.  I needed this in the past but I never had the time and persistence to solve it.  The problem is that if I really *need* it then I usually don't have time to find a good solution.  It's a bit paradoxical, but it's sometimes easier to solve other people's problems than [our own](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59189/12).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following works in both v9 and v10:

```
style = Directive[Thick, Black];

ContourPlot[y - x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black, Opacity[1]], 
 FrameStyle -> style, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, Method -> {FrameStyle -> style}]]
```

The idea to use the (undocumented) `Method` option comes from inspecting the full form of the expression both in v9 and v10.  In v10, it is

```
Legended[Graphics[...], BarLegend[..., Method -> {(* all sorts of graphics options*)}]]
```

In v10, the `Method` part is missing.  This is why belisarius's solution works in v9 only but not in v10.

Thanks to belisarius for providing the main hint for this solution!

Comment: Nice. The `Method` Option is the joker of the deck. They use it for everything. +1

Comment: Nice. Actually you can get away with `BarLegend[Automatic, Method -> {FrameStyle -> Thick}]`. Black frame is default.

Answer (score 5):

```
ContourPlot[y - x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black, Opacity[1]], 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic]] /. 
 HoldPattern[PlotRangePadding -> Automatic] :>
  Sequence[FrameStyle -> Thick, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I tried this in V10 running on OS X -- didn't work.

Comment: @m_goldberg Hmm.. sorry. I can't test it on v10 :(

Comment: Unfortunately, OP is running on V10. I can tell because  his contour plot has the V10 default coloring scheme. So he needs a answer that works on V10.

Comment: @m_goldberg Could you paste the FullForm for the plot somewhere for me?. Perhaps I find an easy way out

Comment: The full form expression is 162000 characters. Maybe we should go to chat to talk further about this? I'm in our main chat room now.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks a lot for trying. I'm not focused on the keyboard right now, so it will be a disturbing to chat with me. I'm sure someone else will find a way!

Comment: Got the solution thanks to your hint!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `"FrameStyle"->Thick` in Version 10:

```
ContourPlot[y - x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black, Opacity[1]],
FrameStyle -> Thick,
PlotLegends ->  BarLegend[Automatic, "FrameStyle" -> Thick]]
```

[image]

In Version 9 (Windows 8 x64) `BarLegend[Automatic, "FrameStyle" -> Thick]` renders only three sides of the frame thick. Using

```
BarLegend[Automatic, "FrameStyle" -> Thick,"AxesStyle"->Thick]
```

gives the desired result.