# How to add own description to BarLegend?

Tags: legending, labeling

Is there a default-option possibility to add own defined names of the contour-labels in `BarLegend`? I want to have a string `"hot"` for 1 and `"cold"` for -1 for this:

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Contours -> {Automatic, 10}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, None]]
```

How can I do this without writing a separate function?

Comment: I believe [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59245/12) should solve the problem. `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, Method -> {Ticks -> {{-1, "Cold"}, {0, "OK"}, {1, "Hot"}}}]`

Comment: @Szabolcs you can drop the `Method`, putting in `Ticks -> ...` directly seems to work.

Answer (score 18):

**Update 3:** The issue mentioned in update 2 below is fixed in version 12.0.

**Update 2:** In version 11.1, the option setting `"Ticks" -> {{-1, "cold"}, {0, "ok"}, {1, "hot"}}` doesn't work (See [Problem with custom ticks in BarLegend in Mathematica 11.1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148464/125)). The tick labels are sorted:

```
 ContourPlot[Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Contours -> {Automatic, 10}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, None, 
   "Ticks" -> {{-1, "cold"}, {0, "ok"}, {1, "hot"}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get the correct labeling of ticks, we can use the option `"TickLabels"`:

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Contours -> {Automatic, 10}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, None, 
   "Ticks" -> {-1, 0, 1}, "TickLabels" -> {"cold", "ok", "hot"}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:**

You can use the (afaik undocumented) option `"Ticks"`

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Contours -> {Automatic, 10}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, None, "Ticks" -> {{-1, "cold"}, {0, "ok"}, {1, "hot"}}]]
```

[image]

Note: You can also use `Ticks` instead of `"Ticks"` and ignore the red highlighting that suggest syntax error.

**Update 1:** Using additional `BarLegend` options `"TickLabels", "TickSide", "TickLengths"`:

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Contours -> {Automatic, 10}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, None, 
   "Ticks" -> {-1, 0, 1}, 
   "TickSide" -> Left, "TickLengths" -> 10, 
   "TickLabels" -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {"cold", "ok", "hot"})]]
```

[image]

Comment: I believe you can use *any* option inside `Method`, like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59245/12).

Comment: @Szabolcs, nice. In version 9 (Windows 8 x 64) we need to use `FrameStyle` with `PlotRangePadding`, i.e., `Method->{FrameStyle->Thick, PlotRangePadding -> 0}`. Without `PlotRangePadding->0` we get what looks like two pairs of horizontal frames.

Comment: Thanks, it solves my problem. By the way, it is strange that the option Ticks allowed in other functions highlights in red for this one, but the result is as one can expect. Isn't it an another bug?

Comment: @szogun, you are welcome. `Ticks` is not a documented option for `BarLegend`; so I don't think we can call it a bug no matter how it behaves/misbehaves:)

Comment: Running mathematica 11.1.1, the first code listing permutes the positions of "hot" "cold", and "ok" so that "ok" is at the top and "hot" is in the middle. The second code listing still gives the correct output.

Comment: Thank you @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs. Strange, isn't it?

Comment: @kglr Ya I experimented a little and I think it sorts the labels in alphabetical order with the beginning of the alphabet at the bottom of the barlegend.

Comment: It doesnt work when you change the color set: BarLegend["SunsetColors" .....} just doisplays two ticks, not three, namely "hot", "ok"