# Legend showing amplitudes of the FFT of an image

Tags: image-processing, fourier-analysis

The FFT amplitudes of the following image

[image]

can be displayed with:

```
fftimg = ImagePeriodogram[img];
Colorize[fftimg, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Green, Red}, #] &)]
```

[image]

To plot a legend I used the following code:

```
fftimgData = ImageData[ImageRotate[fftimg, 90 Degree]];
dim = Dimensions[fftimgData];
x = Range[1, dim[[1]], 1];
y = Range[1, dim[[2]], 1];
data = Flatten[Outer[{#1, #2, fftimgData[[#1, #2]]} &, x, y], 1];

ListDensityPlot[data, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Green, Red}, #] &), 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 5}}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 300}, LegendLabel -> "normalized amplitude", 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 10}], Right]]
```

[image]

**This code is very slow.** (47 sec on my computer)

**What is a better solution to display a legend beside the resulting FFT image showing which brightness (=color) belongs to which amplitude?**

Comment: You can create a custom legend and display it (e.g. `Row` or `GraphicsRow`) next to your image; see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129214/22013).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code performs the FFT manually, rescales it to $[0,1]$ and displays it with the BarLegend you wanted with about 0.2 seconds kernel time and 1s additional display-frontend time needed.

```
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[img];
fftData = Abs[Fourier[ImageData[ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"]]*
     Table[(-1)^(i + j), {i, 1, h}, {j, 1, w}]]];
{fftMin, fftMax} = MinMax[fftData];

colorFunc[v_] := Blend[{Black, Green, Yellow, Orange, Red, White}, v];

Legended[Show[{Colorize[
    Image[(fftData - fftMin)/(fftMax - fftMin)*255], 
    ColorFunction -> colorFunc]}, Frame -> True], 
 BarLegend[{colorFunc[#] &, {0, 1}}, 
  LegendLabel -> Style["normalized\namplitude", 14]]]
```

(Save the graph with the [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html)command otherwise the legend is not included.)

[image]

Comment: This solution is great, thank you. Do you see a possibility to show at the `BarLegend` the real data values `fftData` instead of the brightness values?

Answer (score 2):

**How to add a legend showing the amplitudes instead of brightness values:**

With the help of Julien Kluges answer I have the following code, which is also showing the "frequency" along the axes:

```
img = ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "Grayscale"];

fft = Fourier[ImageData[img]];
fft = RotateLeft[fft, Floor[Dimensions[fft]/2]];

fftAbsData = Abs[fft];

{fftAbsMin, fftAbsMax} = MinMax[fftAbsData];

myColorTable = 
  Flatten@{Table[{Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Orange, Red}, x]}, {x, 1/256, 1, 1/256}]};

g = Colorize[Image[fftAbsData], ColorFunction -> (Blend[myColorTable, #] &)];

myLegend = 
  BarLegend[
    {myColorTable, {fftAbsMin,fftAbsMax}}, 
    LegendLabel -> "amplitude", LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 300}, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 15}
  ];

Legended[
  Graphics[
    Inset[g, Scaled[{.5, .5}], Automatic, Scaled[1]], Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {{"cycles/pixel", ""}, {"cycles/pixel", ""}}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 0.5}, {-0.5, 0.5}}, 
    AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio@g
  ]
  , myLegend
]
```

[image]

With a modified color table:

```
myColorTable = 
  Flatten@{Table[{Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Orange}, x]}, {x, 1/50, 
      1, 1/50}], 
    Table[{Blend[{Orange, Red, White}, x]}, {x, 1/206, 1, 1/206}]};
```

one gets:

[image]

The same way the FFT **for the phases** is:

```
img = ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "Grayscale"];

fft = Fourier[ImageData[img]];
fft = RotateLeft[fft, Floor[Dimensions[fft]/2]];

fftPhasesData = Arg@fft/Pi;

{fftPhasesMin, fftPhasesMax} = MinMax[fftPhasesData];

myColorTable = 
  Flatten@{Table[{Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Orange, Red}, x]}, {x, 1/256, 1, 1/256}]};

g = Colorize[Image[(fftPhasesData - fftPhasesMin)/(fftPhasesMax - 
        fftPhasesMin)], ColorFunction -> (Blend[myColorTable, #] &)];

myLegend = 
  BarLegend[
    {myColorTable, {fftPhasesMin, fftPhasesMax}}, 
    LegendLabel -> "phase (\[Pi])", LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 300}, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 15}
  ];

Legended[
  Graphics[
    Inset[g, Scaled[{.5, .5}], Automatic, Scaled[1]], Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {{"cycles/pixel", ""}, {"cycles/pixel", ""}}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 0.5}, {-0.5, 0.5}}, 
    AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio@g
  ]
  , myLegend
]
```

[image]