# Discrete color bar in ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting, color

I made a plot of a matrix data (around 3000 columns x 2000 row) using ArrayPlot.  The followings are the code and output.

As it is quite difficult to identify the value from a continuous color table, I would like to ask how to plot the graph with a discrete color table and the number of discrete colors can be defined by myself.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
ArrayPlot[data, PlotRange -> Automatic,DataReversed -> {True, False}, ColorFunction -> ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"],PlotLegends -> {Style["Height (m)"], Placed[Automatic, Right]}]
```

[image]

Comment: See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129214/22013) how to make a custom legend.

Comment: hi @corey979, thank you for the suggestion.  I understand that discrete color table can be made via ContourPlot.  However, it takes a very very long to generate a ContourPlot as the size of data is very large.  So I select ArrayPlot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example [Using a given colour table with Image?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21482/121) might be applied here.
Please load the `renderImage` code from my answer there before evaluating the code below.

```
data = Import["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/hailey.dem.gz", "Data"];

Dimensions[data]
```

> ```
> {1201, 1201}
> ```

```
legend = SwatchLegend[
   Array[ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"], 5, {0, 1}],
   Array[N, 5, {Min@data, Max@data}]
   ];

img = 
  renderImage[
    Rescale @ data,
    ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"], 5, ImageSize -> 300];

Labeled[img, legend, Right]
```

[image]

If this performs well for you I can write this into a single function, if you need help doing that.

Comment: This is exactly what I need!!  I will copy your code myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @Mr.Wizard In your example, there are 5 colors.  May I ask what range each colour refers to?  For example, the blue one is from 954 to 1615.5? The 2nd question is can I define another plot range? For example, range of the above data is 954 to 3600. Can I set the legend like {900, 1800, 2700, 3600}? Many thanks!

Comment: @wkong I'll try to come back to this and provide better examples, but for now a brief comment: the original code uses `Round`; that could be replaced with `Floor` or `Ceiling` for different effects, or more complicated methods like `Nearest` or `Interpolation` could also be used.  Additionally the legend above is likely poor because it doesn't really represent what is shown; explicit ranges like [1800, 2400] might be more clear.  Whatever method is used (if `Round` is replaced) should be synchronized with the legend for accuracy.  Clearly this will take a little work.