# Fix Value at the BarLegends

Tags: plotting, legending

I am having trouble fixing a value at the barlegends.

```
contours = Function[{min, max}, Range[min, max, Round[(max - min)/15, 0.01]]];
BarLegend[{"myColorFunction", {0.4, 1}}, contours, 
 LegendLayout -> "Row", LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 40}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 1000]
BarLegend[{"myColorFunction", {0.25, 1}}, contours, 
 LegendLayout -> "Row", LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 40}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

What I want is the first and last value to show up in the barlegends. For example, for the first one value from 0.4 to 1, it would be nice to have contour such that 0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1. So the first and last value is 0.4 and 1.

[image]

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is puzzling that the option `Ticks` (or `"Ticks"`) does not work if you specify the contours in the second argument:

```
bl1a = BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0.4, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 40}, LegendMarkerSize -> 1000, 
  "Ticks" -> Range[.4, 1, .1]]
```

[image]

```
bl1b = BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0.4, 1}}, contours, 
  LegendLayout -> "Row", LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 40}, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> 1000, "Ticks" -> Range[.4, 1, .1]]
```

[image]

A work-around to get both contours and ticks right is to post-process the first output to replace the bar with the one from the second output:

```
RawBoxes[ToBoxes[bl1a] /. 
  RasterBox[___] -> Cases[ToBoxes@bl1b, _RasterBox, All][[1]]]
```

[image]

Similarly for the second example:

```
bl2a = BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0.25, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 40}, LegendMarkerSize -> 1000, 
  "Ticks" -> Append[Range[.25, 1, .1], 1]]

bl2b = BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0.25, 1}}, contours, 
  LegendLayout -> "Row", LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 40}, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> 1000, "Ticks" -> Append[Range[.25, 1, .1], 1]]

RawBoxes[ToBoxes[bl2a] /. 
  RasterBox[___] -> Cases[ToBoxes@bl2b, _RasterBox, All][[1]]]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129811/42190) says that you can use the undocumented `Ticks` option in `BarLegend` to control the contour labels, which I found to do the trick here.

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0.4, 1.}}
 , Ticks -> Subdivide[0.4, 1, 6]
 , LegendLayout -> "Row"
 , LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 40}
 , LegendMarkerSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0.25, 1.}}
 , Ticks -> {0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55, 0.65, 0.75, 0.85, 0.95, 1}
 , LegendLayout -> "Row"
 , LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 40}
 , LegendMarkerSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: No problem! I see that I lost the contours, though. I'm glad the other answer came up.