# Problem with custom ticks in BarLegend in Mathematica 11.1

Tags: bugs, legending, ticks

**Bug introduced in version 11.1 and fixed in 11.3.0**

---

I think the bar legend custom ticks are automatically sorted in *Mathematica* 11.1. Am I making some stupid mistake here or is it a bug?

---

This is with MMA 11.1 Linux

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "Row",  Ticks -> {-1, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

If I try to put custom ticks

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}, LegendLayout->"Row",Ticks ->{{-1, "a"}, {0, "b"}, {1, "c"}}]
```

[image]

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}, LegendLayout->"Row",Ticks ->{{-1, "c"}, {0, "a"}, {1, "b"}}]
```

[image]

It is sorting the tick labels !!!

---

Now with MMA10.4 Linux

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}, LegendLayout->"Row",Ticks ->{{-1, "c"}, {0, "a"}, {1, "b"}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like it is a bug. A work-around is to specify the labels using the option `"TickLabels"`:

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
  "Ticks" -> {-1, 0, 1}, "TickLabels" ->{"c","b","a"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]