# BarLegend not accepting Ticks Option

Tags: legending, ticks

I am using Mathematica 11.1. It says that Ticks is not an option for BarLegend and I don't know how else to specify the **number** of labels which appear in a Bar Legend object. All the pages I have visited say that Ticks is an option for Bar Legend. How can I control the **number** of labels in a Bar Legend? Thanks

Comment: Use `"Ticks"`. see also the Q/As  [Problem with custom ticks in BarLegend in Mathematica 11.1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148464/125) and [How to add own description to BarLegend?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76168/125)

Comment: Hi, I have just tried to use "Ticks" but it shows up in Red Highlight saying that it isn't an option for BarLegend?

Comment: You can do it to some extent with, eg: `Table[BarLegend[{"SolarColors", {0, 1}}, i, LegendMarkerSize -> 500], {i, 1, 6}]`, but it seems to behave oddly. Can you post what you've tried?... Ah, and I'm still using 10.4. So, grain of salt, etc..

Comment: Hi, this is what I've been trying so far: `PlotLegends->BarLegend[{"Rainbow",{0.,zmax}},Ticks->Table[i,{i,0.,zmax,∆z}],

plotdetail,LegendLabel->Placed[Style[legend,fontsize],Above]]`...The Ticks part shows up in Red with or without " ".

Answer (score 8):

I am not quite sure what do you mean with "specify the number of labels". If you have in mind the number of ticks to the right of the BarLegend it can be done as follows

```
Row[{
  ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
   ImageSize -> 200, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, 3]],


  ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
   ImageSize -> 200, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, 6]]
  }]
```

[image]

You may also make a function specifying equally distant ticks

```
contours = Function[{min, max}, Range[min, max, (max - min)/7]];

ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 ImageSize -> 200, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, contours]]
```

giving

[image]

You also may put custom ticks to the BarLegend as in the example below:

```
    ContourPlot[Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Contours -> {Automatic, 10}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[Automatic, None, "Ticks" -> {-1, 0, 1}, 
   "TickSide" -> Left, "TickLengths" -> 10, 
   "TickLabels" -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {"cold", "ok", "hot"})]]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, I did indeed mean the number of ticks. Unfortunately, on my system, it does not recognise `"Ticks"` as an option for `BarLegend`. How might I modify this particular line of code to show just 5 ticks without using `Automatic`? `BarLegend[{"Rainbow", zrange}, plotdetail, 
 LegendLabel -> Placed[Style[legend, fontsize], Above]]`... Thanks

Comment: @Duncan Automatic stays for the ColorFunction and scale. You may specify it according to your liking, such as `BarLegend[{"SolarColors", {0, 1}}, 5]` which will give you the color type, the scale of the legend from 0 to 1 and 5 ticks. Strange, however, that the key "Ticks" does not work for you.