# BarLegend ticks distorted in MatrixPlot

Tags: plotting, color, legending, ticks, undocumented

As shown in many threads here ([this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149416/11125), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148467/11125), ...), `Ticks` is a valid option of `BarLegend`. But it doesn't seem to work well in this simple `MatrixPlot`. Some ticks are just missing and 0.5 is obviously not at its right place (color). Note that I want the default plot with custom ticks. What am I missing here or any workaround?

```
data = Table[Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}];
MatrixPlot[data, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, "Ticks" -> {-0.5, 0, 0.5}], 
 LabelStyle -> Large]
```

[image]

### **Update:**

a more general case with asymmetric data range

```
data = Table[Sin[x] Cos[y] + 0.05 x y, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}]; 
MatrixPlot[data, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, "Ticks" -> {-0.2, 0.5, 1.1}], 
LabelStyle -> Large]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** The function `` Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`HybridRankingAndNaturalScale `` performs the mysterious  ***"scaling based on a mixture of relative value and ranking for each matrix element"***. We construct a piecewise re-scaling function (`reScale`) using `mpReScale` and use it to specify the option value for `"Ticks"`:

```
ClearAll[reScale,  cfMinMax]
reScale[{min_, max_}, {cfmin_, cfmax_}]  := 
  If[# < 0, Rescale[#, {min, 0}, {cfmin, 1/2}], Rescale[#, {0, max}, {1/2, cfmax}]] &;

cfMinMax = MinMax @ Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`HybridRankingAndNaturalScale[
   Union @ SparseArray[#]["NonzeroValues"], 0., {0, 1}, .5] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
data = {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {0, -5, -1}};
ticks = {-4, -2, 3/2, 2};

cfminmax = cfMinMax[data];
minmax = MinMax @ data;
 
Row[{MatrixPlot[data, ImageSize -> 400, 
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic], LabelStyle -> 16, 
   PlotLabel -> "default"], 
  MatrixPlot[data, ImageSize -> 400, 
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, 
     "Ticks" -> (Transpose[{reScale[minmax, cfminmax] /@ #, #}] & @ ticks)], 
   LabelStyle -> 16, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"Ticks : ", ticks}]]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

***An aside:*** We can use another undocumented option  to specify tick labels

```
BarLegend[Automatic, "TickLabels" -> ticks, 
    "Ticks" -> (reScale[minmax, cfminmax] /@ ticks)]
```

to get the picture in the second plot above.

Change `data` and `ticks` to

```
data = Table[Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}];
ticks = {-0.5, 0, 0.5};
```

to get

[image]

Using the second example in OP:

```
data = Table[Sin[x] Cos[y] + 0.05 x y, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}];
ticks = {-0.2, 0.5, 1.1};
```

we get

[image]

With

```
data = 1. + Table[Sin[x] Cos[y] + 0.05 x y, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}, {y, 0, 2 Pi,  0.01}] ;
ticks = {0.1, 0.5, 1.1, 2};
```

we get

[image]

**Original answer:**

This seems to be related to the special way scaling is done in `MatrixPlot` as mentioned in [MatrixPlot >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPlot.html)

[image]

Easiest fix is in OP's case is to change the tick specification to `Transpose[{Rescale[#, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}], #} &@{-0.5, 0, 0.5}]`:

```
MatrixPlot[data, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[Automatic, 
   "Ticks" -> Transpose[{Rescale[#, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}], #} & @ {-0.5, 0, 0.5}]], 
 LabelStyle -> Large]
```

[image]

As an alternative (more general) work-around use the default color function with re-scaled argument and the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`:

```
defaultCF = "DefaultColorFunction" /.
    (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, MatrixPlot])
```

> ```
>  Blend[System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultMatrix, #1] &
> ```

```
MatrixPlot[data, 
 ColorFunction -> (defaultCF[Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, "Ticks" -> {-0.5, 0, 0.5}], 
 LabelStyle -> Large]
```

[image]

Alternatively, specify the color function in `BarLegend`:

```
MatrixPlot[data, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{defaultCF[Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]] &, {-1, 1}}, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, "Ticks" -> {-0.5, 0, 0.5}], 
 LabelStyle -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation! But how about a more general case updated in the question? Your first method doesn't work well. Your second method (if I change `{-1,1}` to `MinMax@data`) produces something rather different from the default plot (maybe zero shifted?). Can I still get the default plot with the tick problem fixed?

Comment: Another issue with your second method is the following. Say we have `data1=data` and another different `data2` (MWE is just `data2=data+1.0`). We then make `plot1` `plot2` and combine as `Grid[{{plot1, plot2}}]`. Then the first BarLegend color is distorted. In any case, to obtain the default plot is probably the first thing. Thank you!

Comment: Hello. I'm sorry that I still find serious flaws. Let's say we use the second `data` in the question and `ticks = {-0.9, 0.5, 1.1}`, then `-0.9` is _missing_ in Method 1. Although `-0.9` is not missing in Method 2/3, the big problem is Method 2/3 in general can give very **different** plot from the original/Method 1. This is not obvious in the current `data`, but very obvious in `data+1.0` for instance. Could you please help with this? Thanks!

Comment: Another example of missing ticks would be the aforementioned `data+1.0` with `ticks={0.5,1.1,2}` where `2` is lost and one can see by eyes that the positions of `0.5` and `1.1` do not match the original BarLegend scale. The current rescale method seems not capturing the default scale well.

Comment: Thank you for the update. This looks to work for the second `data` in the post but not for `data+1.0` mentioned above, which is basically `newdata = Table[ Sin[x] Cos[y] + 0.05 x y + 1, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}]` with `ticks = {0.1, 0.5, 1.1, 2}`. Method 1 loses track of ticks while Method 2 cannot plot normally.

Comment: @xiaohuamao, gave up on the second and third methods. Hope the new version of the first method works for all your cases.

Comment: Thank you so much for your continual help! This now seems to work well as far as I've tried. Now we explicitly make use of the built-in ``Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`HybridRankingAndNaturalScale`` for `MatrixPlot`. Although I'm not sure whether _uniform_ scaling respectively on the positive and negative axis is the built-in scaling, at least piecewise for positive and negative is true. So I feel it is quite plausible and may be the same as the built-in one.

Comment: @xiaohuamao `LinearModelFit` suggests it's indeed uniform scaling. See my answer for  more info.

Answer (score 3):

[kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) has already resolved the problem, here's just some additional analysis and another possible work-around.

First of all, I don't think this is a bug, becauce by default `MatrixPlot` knows how to set proper `Ticks` for `BarLegend`:

```
plot = MatrixPlot[data, ImageSize -> 400, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Looking into the `plot`, we find that:

```
plot[[2, 1]] // InputForm
(*
BarLegend[{Blend[System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultMatrix, #1] & , 
  {0.2889327547713697, 1.}}, LabelStyle -> {}, 
 LegendLayout -> "Column", LegendMarkerSize -> 400, 
 Ticks -> {{0.39446607623278385, -0.5}, {0.5, 0.}, {0.3100389372190109, 
  -0.9}, {0.626985112913238, 0.5}, {0.753970225826476, 1.}, 
  {0.880955338739714, 1.5}, {0.9825434290703043, 1.9000000000000001}}, 
 "PinningPoint" -> 0.5, "SmoothRange" -> False, 
 Charting`TickSide -> Right, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
 *)
```

As we can see, the ticks of `BarLegend` are set by the undocumented `Ticks` option, we plot the ticks:

```
autotick = Cases[plot[[2, 1]], (Ticks -> a_) :> a][[1]] // Sort

ListLinePlot[autotick]
```

[image]

Not hard to notice it's a piecewise line, splitting at `{0.5, 0.}`. We can further verify this with `LinearModelFit`:

```
LinearModelFit[autotick[[#]], {1, x}, x]["RSquared"] & /@ {;; 3, 3 ;;}
(* {1., 1.} *)
```

So, even if we're not aware of the `` Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`HybridRankingAndNaturalScale ``, we can still rescale the ticks in the following manner:

```
ticks = {-0.2, 0.5, 1.1}

Clear[rescale]
rescale[tick_List, rest__] := rescale[#, rest] & /@ tick
rescale[tick_?Positive, mysteryminmax_, {min_, max_}] := 
 Rescale[tick, {0, max}, {1/2, mysteryminmax[[2]]}]
rescale[tick_, mysteryminmax_, {min_, max_}] := 
 Rescale[tick, {min, 0}, {mysteryminmax[[1]], 1/2}]

plot /. (Ticks -> _) :> (Ticks -> {rescale[ticks, 
       Sequence @@ (autotick[[{1, -1}]]\[Transpose])], ticks}\[Transpose])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It further clarifies the problem.