# Create a color gradient using a variable?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Let say I have a function

```
F[x_,y_]:=x^2+6y^(3/2)
```

Now I want to plot a 2D plot of `F[ ]` vs `x` and `y`,  and need to use `y` variable as a color gradient. Here I want to vary `y` as a color axis and the values of `F` will be plotted against `x` it will be like this

[image: F vs x]

but with different function.

The question was asked several day ago [in Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2083160) but I not got any fruitful answer.

Comment: `F[]` is a function of `x` and `y`, how can one create "a 2D plot of `F[ ]` vs `x`"?

Comment: One can also vary y but in the color axis i.e. thiss plot is the 2D projection of the F(x,y) vs x vs y 3D plot

Comment: If it's a 2D projection, shouldn't it be a region like `ParametricPlot[{x, x^2 + 6 y^(3/2)}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -1, 1}]`? Or you just want to plot at a certain `y==a` and use the deriative at `y==a` for coloring?

Comment: Thanks I think your first suggestion about basic parametricplot is correct, but how to show the y as color gradient

Comment: Something like this?: `ParametricPlot[{x, x^2 + 6 y^(3/2)}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{xaxis, yaxis, x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][y]], 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]`

Comment: That is perfect!, But a color axis will make it more detailed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{yL, yR} = {-1, 1}; colorfunc = "Rainbow"; 
ParametricPlot[{x, x^2 + 6 y^(3/2)}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, yL, yR}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{xaxis, yaxis, x, y}, ColorData[colorfunc][y]], 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{colorfunc, {yL, yR}}]]
```

[image]

Do notice this visualization won't work well on those functions oscillating in `y` direction.

Comment: Sorry i think i have forgotted to log scale one axis

Comment: Can you please tell me how to plot this for the case of x and y log axis

Comment: @JohnWick Then how will you handle the plot in `y<=0` range?

Comment: In my case y<=0 is not needed, and also I am facing a issue in merging a list plot with same plotrange with this parametric plot

Comment: @JohnWick Do you need to rescale y axis or both x and y axis?

Comment: I need to rescale y and F[x,y] by logarithmic scale

Comment: @J `{yL, yR} = {1,5};colorfunc="Rainbow";ParametricPlot[{x,x^2 + 6 y^(3/2)}/.y->Exp@y//Evaluate,{x,1,4},{y,Log@yL,Log@yR},PlotRange -> All,ColorFunction->Function[{xaxis, yaxis, x, y},ColorData[colorfunc][y]],AspectRatio-> 1/GoldenRatio, ScalingFunctions -> {Automatic, "Log"}, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{colorfunc, Log@{yL, yR}}, Ticks -> {#, N@Exp@#}\[Transpose] &@{Log@yL, Log@{yL, yR} // Mean, Log@yR}]]` The `Ticks` option in `BarLegend` is undocumented, check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/229502/1871) for some discussion, `ScalingFunctions` is red, but don't worry.

Comment: Actually I am trying to reproduce the plots of https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.00234 paper, i.e. fig.1 or 2, since all of the plots are done with similar procedure

Comment: Now I have asked the question in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/231171/74929