# LegendFunction and MaTeX

Tags: legending, matex

I have started using MaTeX (excellent package to integrate Latex in your wonderful Mathematica generated plots).

I am getting a warning in generating the following plot

```
<< MaTeX`
texStyle = {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", FontSize -> 18};
SetOptions[MaTeX, 
  "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{wasysym}\\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}"}];
f[x_] := ScientificForm[
  N[x /. {NumberForm[y_, {w_, z_}] :> ScientificForm[y, 2]}], 2]
DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"RedBlueTones", "Reverse"}], 
 ImageSize -> {500, Automatic}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendFunction -> f, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 350, 
    LegendLabel -> 
     MaTeX["\\mathrm{Re}(\\mathrm{i}\,I_{\\overline{\\mathrm{D}3}}/L^\
3 T)", Magnification -> 2], LabelStyle -> texStyle], {After, Top}], 
 BaseStyle -> texStyle]
Clear[f]
```

I know that the problem is in using the `LegendFunction` and the `"\\overline"` (when I remove one of the two, no warning is issued).

Comment: This is due to `f` (the LegendFunction) corrupting the Graphics expression returned by MaTeX. Since this function does not seem to do anything here anyway, remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Szabolcs, however the function ```f``` is indeed doing something there. It is ensuring that the legend comes out in Scientific form, and I would like to keep that.

Comment: This is a very crude way to try to change tick marks that affects _all numbers_ within the expression, not just ticks (and is very likely to break something). I suggest you use this way instead: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149416/12