# Mathematica 11.1 BarLegend Bug Resurrected

Tags: bugs, legending, ticks

I am using Mathematica 11.1 and facing difficulty with `BarLegend`. When I specify custom ticks using `"Ticks"` and custom tick labels using `"TickLabels"`, `BarLegend` is still sorting ticks in a strange way. I have, for example:

```
"Ticks"->{-10,-7.5,-5.,-2.5,0.},"TickLabels"->{"-10","-7.5","-5.","-2.5","0."}
```

But the Bar Legend shows up with something like this instead:

```
{-7.5,-5.,-2.5,0.,-7.5,-10.}
```

I have no idea what could be causing this. There is another post that deals with this issue here [Problem with custom ticks in BarLegend in Mathematica 11.1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148464/problem-with-custom-ticks-in-barlegend-in-mathematica-11-1), however, even explicitly specifying the tick labels via `"TickLabels"` isn't working.

Furthermore, both options `"Ticks"` and `"TickLabels"` show up in red highlights and are not being 'fully' recognised as options for `BarLegend`. I know that these options do work for positive numbers but the moment my z range contains negative numbers the BarLegend gets mixed up. This happens even when I convert the tick labels to strings before passing them to BarLegend.

**The same thing happens even when I try to shift the tick range so that it contains only positive numbers.

Comment: This is nothing. Here is a true [BarLegend bug](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Mosquito)

Comment: Works correctly in MMA11.1 Linux, `BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-10, 0}}, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
 "Ticks" -> {-10, -7.5, -5., -2.5, 0.}, 
 "TickLabels" -> {"-10", "-7.5", "-5.", "-2.5", "0."}]`