# How can I replace division sign with slash in ticks of BarLegend

Tags: plotting, legending

I am plotting a Bar legend for the density plot using `BarLegend`. I got the desired bar legend but it has ticks in the form $\frac{\pi}{6},~\frac{\pi}{3},..$, I want them to be like $\pi/6,~\pi/3,...$ I want to write the division using slash. How can I do this in mathematica.

The code I am using is:

```
BarLegend[{Hue[Rescale[#, {0, Pi}, {0, 1}]] &, {π/6 - .1, 2 π/3 + .1}}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium, FontFamily -> "Courier"], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 Ticks -> {π/6, π/3, π/2, 2 π/3}]
```

Comment: Hi Parveen, welcome to MMA.SE! Please consider adding some code to your question - it really helps us help you if we can quickly reproduce your results. I'm pretty sure you want something like `FormatType->StandardForm`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ticks = {π/6, π/3, π/2, 2 π/3};
BarLegend[{Hue[Rescale[#, {0, Pi}, {0, 1}]] &, {π/6 - .1, 2 π/3 + .1}}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium, FontFamily -> "Courier"], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 "Ticks" -> Transpose[{#, # /. Times[Rational[a_, b_], Pi] :> Row[{a Pi, "/", b}]} &@
    ticks}], 
 LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 300}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, add the option `"TickLabels"`:

```
BarLegend[{Hue[Rescale[#, {0, Pi}, {0, 1}]] &, {π/6 - .1, 2 π/3 + .1}}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium, FontFamily -> "Courier"], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, "Ticks" -> ticks, 
 "TickLabels" -> (ticks /. Times[Rational[a_, b_], Pi] :> Row[{a Pi, "/", b}]), 
 LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 300}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Something strange happened. I did copy and paste your code into my mathematica 11 and the ticks got interchanged. However I got the plot as you got but in my case $\pi/6$ appears instead of $\pi/2$. I don't know why!

Comment: @Parveen, it could be  related to version/os. I am using version 11.3 (windows 10).

Comment: Seems so. I am using ubuntu and mathematica 11

Comment: @Parveen, mathematica 11.3 or an earlier version?

Comment: 11.1.0.0 version

Comment: @Parveen, there is a known bug in version 11.1 (see [Problem with custom ticks in BarLegend in Mathematica 11.1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148464/125)).  The second alternative with the `"TickLabels"` option should fix it.

Comment: Thanks. The second alternative doesn't give the ticks in the form of the first one. I want the division sign replaced by slash as done in the first plot.

Comment: @Parveen, you need to use `"Ticks"` and `"TickLabels"` (with quotes " ").

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked now.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this will work:

```
BarLegend[{
  Hue[Rescale[#, {0, Pi}, {0, 1}]] &, {\[Pi]/6 - .1, 2 \[Pi]/3 + .1}
  },
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium, FontFamily -> "Courier"],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 Ticks -> ({#, InputForm@#} & /@ {\[Pi]/6, \[Pi]/3, \[Pi]/2, 
     2 \[Pi]/3})]
```

The idea is to pass a list like `{{x1,label1},{x2,label2}...}` to `Ticks`.

[image]

Since it seems like you know exactly what you want to put into your ticks, you could just put strings:

```
BarLegend[{Hue[Rescale[#, {0, Pi}, {0, 1}]] &, {\[Pi]/6 - .1, 
   2 \[Pi]/3 + .1}}, 
 LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, Bold, Medium, FontFamily -> "Courier"], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 Ticks -> 
  Transpose[{{\[Pi]/6, \[Pi]/3, \[Pi]/2, 2 \[Pi]/3}, {"\[Pi]/6", 
     "\[Pi]/3", "\[Pi]/2", "2\[Pi]/3"}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Seems correct but I want $\pi$ instead of $Pi$ and the upper most tick should be $2\pi/3$ instead of $2*Pi/3$. If you can modify it, then it would be a great help

Comment: @Parveen Check my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks. It works now

Comment: Consider marking the answer (or @kglr's answer, which is at least as good as mine) as accepted if it solved your problem!