# How can I change the thickness of tick marks in BarLegend?

Tags: bugs, legending

**Bug introduced in 10.1 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

[This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59245/12908) explains how to change various undocumented options for `BarLegend` with `Method`. In particular, I want to change the style of the ticks (marks and labels) in `BarLegend`. For example,

```
BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {0, 1}}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12},
 Method -> {Frame -> False, TicksStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[2]]}]
```

However, in Mathematica 10.2 on Linux, `BarLegend` refuses to change the thickness of the tick marks. Also, if I do not add the LabelStyle option then the labels don't change color? In `Plot` this command works,

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},TicksStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[2]]]
```

so I would expect that it works for `BarLegend` as well.

What is going on and is there a workaround to change the thickness of the tick marks? Thanks.

Comment: It seems appropriate to tag this as a bug.

Comment: same issue in version 9.0.1.0.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Somehow the `AbsolutThickness` you specified gets replaced by a default value of `AbsoluteThickness[0.2]`.

This misbehavior can be corrected by replacing the incorrect value with your specification.

```
PlotLegends; (*preload definitions*)

Cell[BoxData[
   MakeBoxes@
      BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {0, 1}}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
       Method -> {Frame -> False, TicksStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[2]]}] /. 
     Directive[RGBColor[1, 0, 0], AbsoluteThickness[_]] -> 
      Directive[RGBColor[1, 0, 0], AbsoluteThickness[2]] // #[[1, 1]] &
   ], "Output"] // CellPrint
```

[image: AbsoluteThickness[2]]

For opaque ticks:

```
Cell[BoxData[
   MakeBoxes@
      BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {0, 1}}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
       Method -> {Frame -> False, TicksStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[2]]}] /. 
     Directive[RGBColor[1, 0, 0], AbsoluteThickness[_]] -> 
      Directive[RGBColor[1, 0, 0], AbsoluteThickness[2], Opacity[1]] // #[[1, 1]] &
   ], "Output"] // CellPrint
```

[image: opaque]

---

Correcting the `BarLegend` of a `DensityPlot`, using the syntax provided in the [answer by Praan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89522/18476) :

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[Automatic, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
    Method -> {Frame -> False, TicksStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[2]]}]] /. 
 Placed[barLegend_BarLegend, args__] :> 
  Placed[ToExpression[
    FrameBox @@ MakeBoxes[barLegend] /. 
      Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[_]] -> 
       Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[2], Opacity[1]]], args]
```

[image: DensityPlot]

The same output can be achieved by using the following `LegendFunction`

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[Automatic, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
   Method -> {Frame -> False, 
     TicksStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[2]]}, 
   LegendFunction -> (# /. 
       Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[_]] -> 
        Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[2], Opacity[1]] &)]]
```

---

With the [answer by Praan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89522/18476) and our discussion in the comments it became clear, that a wrong `InterpretationFunction` inside the `TemplateBox` created by `BarLegend` can cause additional problems.
Compare

```
MakeBoxes[
    BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {0, 1}}, LegendMarkerSize -> 300, 
     LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
     Method -> {FrameStyle -> Black, AxesStyle -> None, 
       TicksStyle -> Black}]] /. 
   AbsoluteThickness[_] -> 
    AbsoluteThickness[2] /. (InterpretationFunction :> 
     f_) -> (InterpretationFunction :> (# &)) // ToExpression
```

[image: corr]

with

```
MakeBoxes[
   BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {0, 1}}, LegendMarkerSize -> 300, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
    Method -> {FrameStyle -> Black, AxesStyle -> None, 
      TicksStyle -> Black}]] /. 
  AbsoluteThickness[_] -> AbsoluteThickness[2] // ToExpression
```

[image: false]

or just the `InterpretationFunction`

```
MakeBoxes[
    BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {0, 1}}, LegendMarkerSize -> 300, 
     LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
     Method -> {FrameStyle -> Black, AxesStyle -> None, 
       TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[2]]}]] /. 
   AbsoluteThickness[_] -> 
    AbsoluteThickness[2] // #[[-1, 2, 1]] & // ToExpression
```

and the first code block in the [answer by Praan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89522/18476).

Comment: Thanks. If I would like to use the BarLegend in a plot, how do I incorporate your solution with PlotLegends? Can the output be converted to a Graphics expression?

Comment: Never mind, I managed to solve it somehow. See my answer below.

Answer (score 11):

**Update:** You can also use the forms given in `` Options[Charting`iBarLegend] `` listed below, i.e., we can use `` Charting`TicksStyle `` for `"TicksStyle"`, `` Charting`Frame `` for `"Frame"`, etc.

```
BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {0, 1}}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
 Charting`TicksStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Red, FontColor -> Black, AbsoluteThickness[5]],
 Charting`Frame -> False,
 Charting`TickLengths -> {20, 10}]
```

[image]

Note: This works for versions 9 thru 11 (Windows 10).

**Original answer:**

Use the (undocumented, afaik) options `"TicksStyle"` and `"FrameStyle"`:

```
BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {0, 1}}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
 "TicksStyle" -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[5]], 
 "FrameStyle" -> Opacity[0]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In version 10, we need to add `Opacity[1]` in `Directive[...]`:

```
BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {0, 1}}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
 "TicksStyle" -> Directive[Opacity[1], Red, FontColor->Black, AbsoluteThickness[5]], 
 "Frame" -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A few more such options:

```
BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {0, 1}}, 
 "LabelStyle" -> Directive[Green, Bold, FontSize -> Scaled[.4]],
  "Ticks" -> Range[0, 1, .1],
 "TicksStyle" -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[5]], 
 "FrameStyle" -> Directive[Dashed, Green], "TickSide" -> Left, 
 "LabelSide" -> Right, "Frame" -> True, "ImageSize" -> {100, 300}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> {100, 500}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** Full list of options

```
Options[Charting`iBarLegend]
```

Version 9:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Version 10:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Can one of these options also solve [this issue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85444/18476)?

Comment: @Karsten7., good question. It seems that Verbeia already tried some of the options. I haven't tried it, but maybe one can change the threshold number 11 which is set in the function ``Legending`LegendDump`iColorBandLegend`` as ``Legending`LegendDump`cthreshold = 11``

Answer (score 4):

#### Analysis

(Observations in 10.1.0 under Windows.)

Curiously it seems that `` AbsoluteThickness[0.2`] `` is hard-coded within the internal definitions.  Formatting of `BarLegend` calls `` Charting`iBarLegend `` which calls `` Legending`LegendDump`iColorGradientLegend `` or `` Legending`LegendDump`iColorBandLegend ``.  In the definition of `iColorGradientLegend` we find:

```
ticksstyle = Switch[ticksstyle,
  Automatic, {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.2`], GrayLevel[0.4`]], 
   Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.2`], GrayLevel[0.4`], Opacity[0.3`]]},
  _?Charting`generalDirective | {_?
      Charting`generalDirective ..} | {}, (Charting`ConstructDirective[#1, 
      AbsoluteThickness[0.2`]] &) /@ Charting`padList[ticksstyle, 2],
  None | False, None,
  _, (Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.2`], #1] &) /@ {GrayLevel[0.4`], 
    Directive[GrayLevel[0.4`], Opacity[0.5`]]}]
```

If the option value passed to this inner function is a "generalDirective" we specifically get:

```
(Charting`ConstructDirective[#1, 
  AbsoluteThickness[0.2`]] &) /@ Charting`padList[ticksstyle, 2]
```

So the program is appending `` AbsoluteThickness[0.2`] `` to anything we specify by way of `` Charting`ConstructDirective ``.  This seems at best a poor design in my opinion.

#### Work-around

Seeing the cause of the problem inspires an unusual work-around; here is a `chomp` head that consumes the argument to its right and then vanishes:

```
chomp /: h_[a___, chomp[x__], b_, c___] := h[a, x, c]
```

Now when used on our `AbsoluteThickness` spec *making sure it is the last*:

```
BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {0, 1}}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
 Method -> {Frame -> False, 
   TicksStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[1], chomp @ AbsoluteThickness[4]]}]
```

[image]

One could also enter `Directive[chomp[ Red, Opacity[1], AbsoluteThickness[4] ] ]`.

Answer (score 3):

I went back to the [old legend functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6380/245) that I used before `BarLegend` existed, and tried the following:

- First, copy the definitions of `trimPoint`, `colorLegend`, `display` and `at` by selecting the large code block in the section **Color bar legend**.

Then do this:

```
display[{
  colorLegend[
    ColorData["SunsetColors"],
    {-.5, .5},
    LabelStyle -> 
     Directive[Yellow, FontSize -> 12, FontWeight -> Bold],
    "ColorBarFrameStyle" -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], Cyan],
    Background -> Darker@Darker@Darker@Blue,
    "ColorSwathes" -> None,
    Contours -> 10,
    RoundingRadius -> 15,
    BoxFrame -> 3,
    "Digits" -> 2] // at[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]},
 ImageSize -> 80,
 AspectRatio -> 4]
```

[image: bar legend]

The thickness information can be put either into the option `"ColorBarFrameStyle"` or `LabelStyle`. To show how these options differ, I highlighted their targets in different colors (`Yellow` for `LabelStyle` and `Cyan` for the `"ColorBarFrameStyle"`.

So this older legend functionality has the ability to customize thicknesses as you were asking. It doesn't require `BarLegends`, which makes it useable in *Mathematica* version 8, too. The workings of the positioning commands `display` and `at` are explained with more examples in the linked answer. Normally, you would use `display` to combine the legend bar with a figure. Then the `AspectRatio` and `ImageSize` options will have to be adjusted to fit both objects.

Answer (score 3):

In the [answer of Karsten 7.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89490/12908) the `BarLegend` is shown as a Cell expression, and since I want to use the legend in an actual plot, it is not immediately useful. However, with the help of his/her answer, I managed to solve my problem.

First I make the legend:

```
barLegend = ToExpression[FrameBox@@MakeBoxes[
  BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {0, 1}}, LegendMarkerSize -> 300,
    LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12},
    Method -> {FrameStyle -> Black, AxesStyle -> None, TicksStyle -> Black}]] /. 
AbsoluteThickness[_] -> AbsoluteThickness[2]];
```

I don't know how changing the head to `FrameBox` works, but without this, the thickness of the tick marks reverts back to the default value `AbsoluteThickness[0.2]` during `ToExpression`.

This legend can then be used in a plotting environment, for example `DensityPlot`:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x+y^2],{x, 0, 3},{y, 0, 3},
  PlotLegends -> barLegend, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12},
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["SunsetColors"], ImageSize -> 300]
```

**Edit**

See the update of [Karsten 7's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89490/12908) for a nice implementation; doing the replacement after the plot command has been evaluated.

Comment: Your `ToExpression`  `FrameBox@@MakeBoxes` combination makes this think much more convenient. With `FrameBox@@` you are replacing `TemplateBox` with `FrameBox`.

Comment: With a fresh kernel the first code block will produce an error message. One has to evaluate `PlotLegends` first to load some definitions.

Comment: @Karsten 7. Thanks! I know about the infix notation `@@` of `Apply`. I just don't know why  `Framebox` keeps the new thickness value while `TemplateBox` reverts it back to the default value.

Comment: By replacing `TemplateBox` with `FrameBox` you basically  inactivate the `InterpretationFunction` and the other stuff part of the `TemplateBox`.