# How to customize legend tick thickness?

Tags: plotting, legending

I want to customize the frame and ticks of the `BarLegend`, but according to the documentation it does not support standard `Graphics` options. Perhaps there is a hack possible?

More specifically I want the frame and ticks to be with a fixed `AbsoluteThickness` and `Black`.

When testing, I figured out that although in conflict with documentation

```
BarLegend[{"SolarColors", {0, 1}}, 5, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

[image]

does actually change the colour and thickness of the frame, but not the thickness of the tick. **How to also change the thickness of the tick?**

Comment: does `BarLegend[{"SolarColors", {0, 1}}, 5 , 
 "TicksStyle" ->   Directive[ Red, FontColor->Black, AbsoluteThickness[5]], "FrameStyle" -> Directive[Red, Thick]]` work in your version /OS?

Comment: Yes, it works and I would accept this as an answer. How do you discover `" "` options?

Comment: Johu, as I was searching where else I used `"TicksStyle"` i found  [How can I change the thickness of tick marks in BarLegend?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89422/125) which looks like a duplicate/ almost duplicate. It probably was during one of those spelunking expeditions where I bumped into ``Charting`iBarLegend`` and ``Options[Charting`iBarLegend]`` .

Comment: I agree, it is a dublicate. I really did try to search before my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BarLegend[{"SolarColors", {0, 1}}, 5, 
  "TicksStyle" -> Directive[ Red, FontColor -> Black, AbsoluteThickness[5]], 
  "FrameStyle" -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

[image]

This works in version 9 / Windows 10 and version 11.3 / Wolfram Cloud.