# BarLegend frameticks formatting

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, legending

I'm trying to change the default BarLegend ticks style using the officially documented methods, but nothing changes. I've tried the `Method` method (`Method -> {FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 12]}`) as it was suggested here (*[Changing BarLegend border style](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59232/changing-barlegend-border-style?newreg=33e273a122a544f0899f221466b68842)*), but again nothing happened. How can I solve this problem?

The function I'm trying to plot is:

```
 DensityPlot[func[a,b], {a, 0, 7}, {b, -0.5, 0},
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", ImageSize -> 1080, Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> Automatic, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, 20, Black],
 FrameLabel -> {Style[a, 25, Black], Style[b, 25, Black]}, PlotPoints -> 50,
 PlotLegends ->
  BarLegend[Automatic,
   Method -> {FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black],
     FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Orange, 12]}]]
```

This code returns the following figure.

[image: Result]

As you can see, `FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, 20, Black]` perfectly works for main plot, but it does nothing with colorbar.

So I'd like to have similar frame ticks and values formatting for the main frame and for colorbar.

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you're trying to achieve, and can you include the code for a minimum working example that displays the issue you're having?

Comment: I've just tried to do my best with this update @CarlLange

Comment: Yes, that's loads better, thank you!

Comment: Does `PlotLegends -> 
 BarLegend[Automatic, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, 20, Black]]`  work for you?

Comment: Ah, in fact you can pass `TicksStyle` as well in a `Method` option: `PlotLegends -> 
 BarLegend[Automatic, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
  Method -> {TicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, 20, Black]]`

Comment: Without `Method` there's an error (at least my Mathematica 13.0.0 paints in red `FrameStyle` ).  With `Method` it doesn't work.

Comment: `FrameStyle` should still work, even though the syntax checker doesn't believe you (it does for me on 13.0) - although you can pass it in the `Method` as well.

Comment: @CarlLange can you please post your comment as an answer to this question? I'd like to mark it as the correct solution for this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of `LabelStyle` and the `Method` hack in the linked question to get a consistent style for the `BarLegend`:

```
DensityPlot[func[a, b], {a, 0, 7}, {b, -0.5, 0}, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", ImageSize -> 1080/2, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> Automatic, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, 20, Black], 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[a, 25, Black], Style[b, 25, Black]}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[Automatic, LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, 20, Black], 
   Method -> {TicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
     FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]}]]
```

It turns out the `BarLegend` uses `Ticks` for the ticks, rather than `FrameTicks`. I'm not completely sure if that's a new change!

[image]