# Axes behind plot lines

Tags: graphics

If I do a plot and want both the horizontal axis and a frame I can do this:

```
Plot[Sin[2 π 10 t], {t, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]},
 Frame -> True, Axes -> True,
 AxesStyle -> {{Orange, Thickness[0.01]}, {Orange, Thickness[0.01]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The axis is in front of the plotted line. However, because of [this useful post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26918/12558) we can do

```
Plot[Sin[2 π 10 t], {t, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]},
 Frame -> True, Axes -> True,
 AxesStyle -> {{Orange, Thickness[0.01]}, {Orange, Thickness[0.01]}},
 Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and the axes is behind the line. Now I wish to do this with `ListLinePlot` but then I get

```
data = Table[{t, Sin[2 π 10 t]}, {t, 0, 1, 0.005}];
ListLinePlot[data,
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]},
 Frame -> True, Axes -> True,
 AxesStyle -> {{Orange, Thickness[0.01]}, {Orange, Thickness[0.01]}},
 FrameStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.001]},
 Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and the axis is back in front of the line.  How to I get the axes behind the lines for a `ListLinePlot`?  Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data = Table[{t, Sin[2 π 10 t]}, {t, 0, 1, 0.005}];
```

Use [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html)

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[data,
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> True,
 AxesStyle -> {{Orange, Thickness[0.01]},
   {Orange, Thickness[0.01]}},
 FrameStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.001]},
 Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent. How do you know these things?

Comment: @Hugh - your question shows that `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}` works with **some** graphics functions. Experimentation then reveals that the `Method` has been implemented with `Show`.