# How to send the axes' labels of a ListLinePlot behind the plotted curve?

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling, plot-themes

I want the axes' digits of my plots (actually ListLinePlots) to be free from the interference with other background elements (specifically grid lines). To do that I've tried specifying `Background->White` in the `TickLabels` option. However, since they're printed on top of the function curve, the white background of the labels hides the function curve when they happen to overlap. Here is a picture of the issue:

[image]

(The desired effect is as in the bottom label shown in the image, without the problem of the label circled in red.)

I would like the axes labels to lay in a layer between the background elements and the plotted curve. I have seen a couple of questions relevant to this ([1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/195324/69212) and [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26917/69212)), but they do not specifically address this issue. (Using `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}` solves indeed the problem when it's a `Plot`, but has no effect with `ListLinePlot`.)

Not sure if this is possible, but I was looking for some solution that does not use any external package.

Here is an example:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[2 x + 2, {x, -5, 5}], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick], 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[30, Black, Background -> White], 
 PlotTheme -> {"Grid"}, GridLinesStyle -> Plain, 
 Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```

[image: Note how the digit 4 background overlaps]

Comment: [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)? Also, what have you tried so far? Please provide a MWE for us to work off of to help you :)

Comment: @ CA Trevillian Thank you so much for the comment. I added an example and while creating it I observed something important: `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}` does indeed work perfectly when we have a `Plot`, but it has no effect when it's a `ListLinePlot`...

Comment: What do you mean “when you have a plot”? When using `Plot`? Can you, perhaps, observe success when using `ListPlot`? Did you see what Epilog does? Seemingly this is what you want.

Comment: @ CA Trevillian I mean when plotting using the function `Plot`, as opposed to the function `ListLinePlot`. I haven't considered `Epilog` since that requires manual input of the label coordinates... and I have a very high number of plots that need to manage automatically. Even in that case wouldn't `Epilog` plot on top of everything?

Comment: correct—I suggest to use `Epilog` to plot the curve on top of everything. Also perhaps `ListPlot` works with the method you mention, using `Joined->True`. This would be convenient for your use if so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Show[ListLinePlot[Table[2 x + 2, {x, -5, 5}], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick], 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[30, Black, Background -> White], 
  PlotTheme -> {"Grid"}, GridLinesStyle -> Plain], 
 Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```

[image]

Comment: kglr thanks! any idea why it doesn’t work directly as option on `ListLinePlot` and it does a posteriori via `Show`? I’d like to know if there are more solutions though; this happens to have the effect of behaving differently after rasterizing it as an image: it’s no longer RGB and has 4 channels (what might happen to matter in my case); otherwise this might do indeed for me.

Comment: @abcd, i am also puzzled why `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}` works in `Plot` but not in `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: you can also use `Epilog` as CA Trevillian suggested in comments: `ListLinePlot[tbl = Table[2 x + 2, {x, -5, 5}], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick], 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[30, Black, Background -> White], 
 PlotTheme -> {"Grid"}, GridLinesStyle -> Plain, 
  Epilog -> ListLinePlot[tbl][[1]]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

As alternatives you can either shift the `AxesOrigin`

```
ListLinePlot[Table[2 x + 2, {x, -5, 5}],
 PlotStyle -> Thick,
 TicksStyle -> Directive[30, Black],
 PlotTheme -> {"Grid"},
 GridLinesStyle -> Plain,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, -10}]
```

[image]

or use a `Frame`

```
ListLinePlot[Table[2 x + 2, {x, -5, 5}],
 PlotStyle -> Thick,
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[30, Black],
 PlotTheme -> {"Grid"},
 GridLinesStyle -> Plain,
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}]
```

[image]