# Show displaying graphic behind axes in 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have the following image:

[image]

Where I use Show to plot the Sun, created with BubbleChart3D, and the two concentric spheres with axes, generated using SphericalPlot3D.

I've tried using `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}` as suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195324/axes-behind-plot-lines) but this did not work.

My other option is to try and make the axis transparent just in the region where the Sun is plotted, but I haven't found a way to do this yet.

Is there any known way to ensure that the sun object gets plotted above the axis?

Code:
Shell and axis

```
shells = SphericalPlot3D[{6, 10}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 
   2 Pi},  Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, ImageSize -> Large, 
  Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.1]], 
    Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.05]]},
  PlotRange -> {{-14, 14}, {-14, 14}, {-14, 14}},
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(g\)]\) [kpc]", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(g\)]\) [kpc]", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(g\)]\) [kpc]"},
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 15],
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 15],
  Ticks -> {{{-0.75, "\[Pi]/4", 0}, 6, {-8, "Sun", 0}, 
     10}, {}, {}, {}},
  TicksStyle -> Directive[{Opacity[1]}]
  ]
```

Sun

```
sun = BubbleChart3D[{{-8, 0, 0, 4}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-11, 11}, {-11, 11}, {-11, 11}}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  ChartElementFunction -> (Ellipsoid[#2[[;; 3]], 
      0.1 #2[[4]] {1, 1, 1/0.6/GoldenRatio}] &),
  Boxed -> False,
  Axes -> False,
  FaceGrids -> None
  ]
```

Show

```
Show[{shells, sun}, Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```

Note: `Show[{sun, shells}]` removes the axes altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is easier to adapt the graphics to your needs if you use basic commands instead of high level constructs:

```
Graphics3D[{
  {Gray, Opacity[0.05], Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 10]},
  {Gray, Opacity[0.1], Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 6]},
  Thickness[0.005], 
  Line[{{{-14, 0, 0}, {14, 0, 0}}, {{0, -14, 0}, {0, 14, 0}}, {{0, 
      0, -14}, {0, 0, 14}}}],
  Line[{{{6, 0, 0}, {6, 0, -0.5}}, {{10, 0, 0}, {10, 0, -0.5}}}],
  Style[Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(g\)]\) [kpc]", {15, 0, 1}], 
   12, Bold], 
  Style[Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(g\)]\) [kpc]", {0, 15, 1}], 
   12, Bold], 
  Style[Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(g\)]\) [kpc]", {0, 0, 15}], 
   12, Bold],
  Style[Text["\[Pi]/4", {-1, 0, 1}], 12, Bold],
  Style[Text["Sun", {-10, 0, -2}], 12, Bold],
  {RGBColor[1, 0.8, 0], Ball[{-8, 0, 0}, 0.6]}
  }, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: I only shared a part of the graphic. The full one has some more complicated 3D elements, although this does give me some new ideas to try and solve the issue, and does solve the problem as stated, so thank you very much!

Comment: Also, when I copy this exactly to my notebook it plots the sphere behind the line element...

Comment: MAking the ball larger should help. Try: Ball[{-8, 0, 0}, 0.8]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Daniel Huber for the inspiration. I ended up making separate lines on either side of my Sun object as follows

```
newroi = Graphics3D[{
   {Gray, Opacity[0.05], Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 10]}, {Gray, Opacity[0.1], 
    Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 6]}, Thickness[0.0009], 
   Line[{{{-12, 0, 0}, {-8.25, 0, 0}}, {{0, -12, 0}, {0, 12, 0}}, {{0,
        0, -12}, {0, 0, 12}}}],
   Line[{{{-7.7, 0, 0}, {12, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
       0}, {0, 0, 0}}}], 
   Line[{{{6, 0, 0}, {6, 0, -0.5}}, {{10, 0, 0}, {10, 0, -0.5}}}], 
   Style[Text[
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(g\)]\) [kpc]", {13, 0, -0.5}], 25], 
   Style[Text[
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(g\)]\) [kpc]", {0, 13, 0.5}], 25], 
   Style[Text[
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(g\)]\) [kpc]", {0, -1, 13.2}], 25], 
   Style[Text["\[Pi]/4", {-1, 0, 0.7}], 20], 
   Style[Text["6", {6, 0, 0.5}], 20], 
   Style[Text["10", {10, 0, 0.5}], 20],
   Style[Text["Sun", {-8, 0, -1.3}], 20],
   {Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[None], 
    Cone[{{-11, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 11]},
   {RGBColor[1, 0.8, 0], Ball[{-8, 0, 0}, 0.3]}
   },
  Boxed -> False]
```

With the result
[image]