# Does Mathematica have a built-in tool that allows one to operate on both sides of an equation?

Tags: equation-solving

Geogebra has a very neat CAS view that allows one to solve an equation step by step in the following fashion:

> $\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad $[image]

You type an equation and can then apply operations to both sides of the equation, as shown in step 2. Does Mathematica have some built in functionality that allows the user to do the same? It's possible to program something to do it, but I'd like to know if Mathematica already has this feature. The help section on equation manipulation does not contain information about this.

Comment: A start: `Thread[(3 x + 8 == 16)/16, Equal]`

Comment: Or `eqn=3x+8==16; Map[1/16*#&,eqn]`, or `Distribute[1/16 eqn,Equal]`

Comment: In Maple, all this works out of the box as is. I always wondered why in Mathematica these things are so much harder. Here is screen shot from my Maple session now ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fs0fY.png) (ofcourse, there are things that are much harder to do in Maple than in Mathematica as well)

Comment: Per Nasser's 2017 answer below, there are now (as of v. 11.3) built-in commands for this like `ApplySides[]`, likely making many of the other answers obsolete.

Answer (score 43):

Working off of [m_goldberg's idea](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86928/8253), we can make it look a little nicer by using `$Pre` and `$PrePrint` to make equations behave as lists but still display as equations:

```
CASViewOn[] := (
  $Pre = If[Head[#] === Equal, List @@ #, #] &; 
  $PrePrint = If[Head[#] === List, Equal @@ #, #] &;
);
CASViewOff[] := (
  $Pre =.;
  $PrePrint =.;
);
```

Now we can do

```
CASViewOn[]

3 x + 8 == 16
```

> ```
> 8 + 3 x == 16
> ```

```
% - 8
```

> ```
> 3 x == 8
> ```

```
%/3
```

> ```
> x == 8/3
> ```

```
CASViewOff[]
```

---

Here's another way: write the equations using an undefined operator like `DotEqual` (entered with <kbd>esc</kbd>`.=`<kbd>esc</kbd>) and then define the threading behavior that we want.

Define automatic threading for arithmetic operations with

```
DotEqual /: ((f : Plus | Times | Divide | Power)[x___, DotEqual[y__], z___]) := 
  DotEqual @@ f @@ ({x, {y}, z} /. DotEqual -> List)
```

Now we can do

```
3 x^2 + 1 ≐ 5
```

> ```
> 1 + 3 x^2 ≐ 5
> ```

```
% - 1
```

> ```
> 3 x^2 ≐ 4
> ```

```
%/3
```

> ```
> x^2 ≐ 4/3
> ```

```
Sqrt[%] // PowerExpand
```

> ```
> x ≐ 2/Sqrt[3]
> ```

Also we can add or multiply by another equation:

```
% + (2 y - x ≐ 0)
```

> ```
> 2 y ≐ 2/Sqrt[3]
> ```

Convert to a regular equation with

```
% /. DotEqual -> Equal
```

> ```
> 2 y == 2/Sqrt[3]
> ```

Answer (score 37):

Yes, it has. This is your example equation:

```
    eq1 = 3 x + 8 == 16

(*  8 + 3 x == 16  *)
```

Here is its TreeForm:

```
TreeForm[eq1]
```

[image]

As you see, there are two elements on the first level:

```
    eq1[[1]]
eq1[[2]]

(*  8 + 3 x

16   *)
```

which are the left- and right-hand parts of the equation. Any equation in Mma has such a form, that is, left- and right-hand parts as the only elements in the first level. In order to apply an operation to the both parts of this equation one needs, therefore, to map this operation onto the equation like the following: `Map[OperationInQuestion, eq1]`. The peculiarity is that all the operations we might want to map are dyadic operations, that is the operator has two arguments. To handle this one needs to use the "slot-ampersand" (`#-&`) notation. For example, if we need to multiply the both sides of the equation by the same factor, `factor` we need to use the `Times[#,factor]&` operator of multiplication. The whole operator acting on the equation will have the form `Map[Times[#,factor]&, equation]`.

Let us now turn to your example equation `eq1`, and I will demonstrate how all this works. Let us first divide the both parts of `eq1` by 16:

```
 eq2 = Map[Expand[Divide[#, 16]] &, eq1]

(* 1/2 + (3 x)/16 == 1  *)
```

I also wraped it by `Expand`just to open the parentheses. Let us now add -1/2 to the both parts:

```
 eq3 = Map[Plus[#, -1/2] &, eq2]

(*  (3 x)/16 == 1/2  *)
```

Let us now divide it by 3/16:

```
    eq4 = Map[Divide[#, 3/16] &, eq3]

(*   x == 8/3   *)
```

Like this one may treat any equation.

Have fun!

Comment: Frankly, I would write `eq2 = Map[Expand[Divide[#, 16]] &, eq1]` in practice as `eq2 = Expand[#/16] & /@ eq1`. Was there a specific (non-educational) point in writing `Divide` and `Plus` explicitly?

Comment: agree @kirma, I was kind of surprised by the code above myself... I wouldn't even bother with `Expand`, I'd just use `eq2 = #/16 & /@ eq1`

Comment: @vaxquis Well, that is up to you. After some (rather short) it will become obvious. I would like to point out that such step-by-step operating on expressions (and not oly equations) I use not for teaching purpose at all. Using these as well as others tricks (not shown in my answer) I make my calculations in theoretical physics. Very efficient too.

Comment: @kirma "Was there a specific (non-educational) point in writing Divide and Plus?"  These are the full forms of the corresponding operations. Try `a+b//FullForm `to check it. They are nor worse that the traditional form, but as soon as one needs to make such a calculation as above they are handy.

Comment: @kirma "Frankly, I would write eq2 = Map[Expand[Divide[#, 16]] &, eq1] in practice as eq2 = Expand[#/16] & /@ eq1"  Do you see any difference?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Yes, my point was that although full forms are correct and identical to short forms, it is pretty unlikely a seasoned user would write `Plus` or `Divide` explicitly (otherwise than as a demonstration) on these cases. Maybe I'm just a bit too nit-picky... :)

Comment: Alexei: there's nothing "efficient" in verbosity. Being overly verbose makes the issue at hand less visible. We created math notation to restrict verbosity and promote clearness. Saying "`*` operator" is IMO a lot better than saying "multiplication operator" - because it highlights the symbolism of the operation. One may not know if "multiplication operator" is `x`, `*`, `.` or anything else, since there are *many* types of multiplications. Also, it's not "slot-ampersand notation", it's a *pure function*. It's not just a notation, it's an important semantic difference.

Comment: @kirma: you're not nit-picky; I've had this problem with some students, taught the "schooly" way of full expressions, `for` loops, unpure functions etc. When shown a *real* Mathematica code, with actual operator usage, they would tilt their heads and say "*WTF is that? How does that even work? ...*" - even more, they would *rewrite* each and every line of the code to their "*understandable*" form, replacing eg. ∫ with `Integrate[]`, π symbol with `Pi`, every `/@` with for loop over the array index... I see those "Wittgenstein's ladders" a severe teaching/learning obstacle.

Answer (score 36):

I usually find it easier to do this kind of manual equation munging by first converting the equation to a list, carrying out the operations on the  list (convenient because math operations thread over lists), and then converting back to an equation when done.

**Example**

```
List @@ (3 x + 8 == 16)
```

> {8 + 3 x, 16}

```
% - 8
```

> ```
> {3 x, 8}
> ```

```
%/3
```

> ```
> {x, 8/3}
> ```

```
Equal @@ %
```

> ```
> x == 8/3
> ```

Comment: changing the heads to simplify the operations to the bare minimum... just brilliant!

Comment: @m_goldberg I agree, I also often use this trick. There are, however, two different situations: (1) when without transforming to the list the operation cannot be done, and (2) when one can do the same either with or without going to a list. The first case arises, if Mma might make an undesireble simplification of terms in the course of transformation. In such a case the list form prevents it.

Comment: @m_goldberg I discovered this page and tried your command `List @@ 3 x + 8 == 16`, but Mathematica (10.3.0.0 on Mac OS X 10.11.1) returned *8 + 3x == 16`. Has something changed? Also, I am searching for a page in Mathematica Stack Exchange that shows how to do a variety of manipulations like these. If you are familiar with the location, can you add a comment with the link? Thanks.

Comment: @m_goldberg Aha. This worked: `List @@ (3 x + 8 == 16)`.

Comment: @David. Yes, you found a bug in my answer. I omitted the parentheses. Thanks for pointing it out. I will correct the answer.

Answer (score 13):

This is interesting. I just happened to see the Wolfram design video for 11.3 features, posted here https://www.twitch.tv/videos/207012986  and starting at 45:05, there is almost 30 minutes discussion on new functions just to work on both sides of equations and inequalities. I happened to have screen shots of these new commands (taken from the video, so they might not be too clear).  There are basically 5 new commands

`AddSides, SubtraceSides, MultiplySides, DivideSides, ApplySides`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Some usage examples by Wolfram

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is an example using these function to complete the squares in the help

[image]

It all looks very useful. We have to wait for 11.3 to see them. I hope they will be all there.

Answer (score 6):

`EqualThread`, MathSource 0209-124 has been fulfilling that need for me since the 90's.  I put it in my Init file.

```
<< EqualThread.m

eq = 3 x + 8 == 16;

eq/6 // Apart
(* x/2+4/3==8/3 *)

eq - 8
(* 3 x==8 *)

Log[(eq - 8)/3]
(* Log[x] == Log[8/3] *)
```

etc.  It seems to work in all MMa versions.

I don't know why Wolfram did not build it into the Kernel.  Maybe they found problems, but it has always worked for me.

Comment: Is there a place to download this .m file from?

Comment: Download from http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4491/