# cancel out the common terms and factor out the common terms and extract the coefficients

Tags: matrix, algebraic-manipulation

the following code fail to multiply each equation by dt, since dt does not seem to do any jobs. it remains as a common factor, I would like it to cancel out the 1/dt term and also multiply the rest of them with dt.

```
eqns = {x1'[t] == (\[Mu] - (x1^2 + x2^2)) x1 - x3x2 + 
    Ksin + \[Sigma]dw/dt, 
  x2'[t] == (\[Mu] - (x1^2 + x2^2)) x2 + (x3x1), 
  x3'[t] == -(Ksin + \[Sigma]dw/dt) x2}

sort1 = eqns /. {x1'[t] -> dx1/dt, x2'[t] -> dx2/dt, 
    x3'[t] -> dx3/dt} // MatrixForm

sort2 = sort1*dt
```

what I would like to see is

```
dx1 == dt Ksin - dt x1^3 - dt x1 x2^2 - dt x3x2 + 
  dt x1 \[Mu] + \[Sigma]dw
dx2 == -dt x1^2 x2 - dt x2^3 + x3x1dt + dt x2 \[Mu]
dx3 == -x2 (dt Ksin + \[Sigma]dw)
```

besides,if it works as what I expect, how can you extract the terms/coefficients that includes the dt and dw seperately?  it should look like the following expressions

```
dx1=dt(Ksin-x1^3-x1x2^2-x3x2+x1\[Mu])+(\[Sigma])dw)
dx2 == dt(-x1^2 x2 - x2^3 + x3x1 + x2 \[Mu])
dx3 == -dt(Ksin) + (\[Sigma])dw
```

if possible, can we make them as a matrix form?

since I would like to use the following terms elsewhere to do some other analysis

```
Ksin-x1^3-x1x2^2-x3x2+x1\[Mu]
-x1^2 x2 - x2^3 + x3x1 + x2 \[Mu]
```

Sincerely,
Li

Comment: does it work if you replace `sort1 = eqns /. {x1'[t] -> dx1/dt, x2'[t] -> dx2/dt, 
    x3'[t] -> dx3/dt} // MatrixForm` with `(sort1 = eqns /. {x1'[t] -> dx1/dt, x2'[t] -> dx2/dt, 
     x3'[t] -> dx3/dt}) // MatrixForm` ? The MatrixForm is a wrapper which gets in the way of your computation. This is a common problem. If this still does not solve your problem, you could update the question with corrected code.

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work. do you have any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Better yet, use MultiplySides (which I learned about from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161787/34831) answer).

```
eqns = {x1'[t] == (\[Mu] - (x1^2 + x2^2)) x1 - x3 x2 + Ksin + \[Sigma]dw/dt,
        x2'[t] == (\[Mu] - (x1^2 + x2^2)) x2 + x3 x1,
        x3'[t] == -(Ksin + \[Sigma] dw/dt) x2};
sort = First@Solve[eqns, {x1'[t], x2'[t], x3'[t]}] /. Rule -> Equal;
sort2 = MultiplySides[sort, dt, Assumptions -> dt != 0];
sort3 = sort2 /. {x1'[t] -> dx1/dt, x2'[t] -> dx2/dt, x3'[t] -> dx3/dt} // TableForm
```

which produces

```
{
 {dx1 == dt Ksin - dt x1^3 - dt x1 x2^2 - dt x2 x3 + dt x1 \[Mu] + \[Sigma]dw},
 {dx2 == dt (-x1^2 x2 - x2^3 + x1 x3 + x2 \[Mu])},
 {dx3 == -x2 (dt Ksin + dw \[Sigma])}
}
```

To extract coefficients do the following

```
beloweqns1 = {dx1/dt == (a + b + c) dt + (e + f) dw, 
              x2/dt == (a1 + a2 + a3) dt + (e1 + e2) dw};
Coefficient[beloweqns1[[1, 2]], dt]
Coefficient[beloweqns1[[1, 2]], dw]
Coefficient[beloweqns1[[2, 2]], dt]
Coefficient[beloweqns1[[2, 2]], dw]
```

To understand the indexing on `beloweqns` above, use `TreeForm[beloweqns]`.

---

I think you want to use

```
Distribute[sort1*dt, Equal]
```

because otherwise Mathematica treats the equation as a symbolic object.

Comment: unfortunately, I tried MultiplySides and the Distribute as mentioned above, none of them work. can you give me some other feasible solutions? but still, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Hi dskeletov, eventually, I figured it out how to make it work. the following is my new code, I hope that it could be helpful for other people.`eqns = {x1'[t] == (\[Mu] - (x1^2 + x2^2)) x1 - x3x2 + 
    Ksin + \[Sigma]dw/dt, x2'[t] == (\[Mu] - (x1^2 + x2^2)) x2 + x3x1,
   x3'[t] == -(Ksin + \[Sigma]dw/dt) x2},        sort = First@Solve[eqns, {x1'[t], x2'[t], x3'[t]}] /. Rule -> Equal,     sort2 = MultiplySides[sort, dt, Assumptions -> dt != 0],      sort3 = sort2 /. {x1'[t] -> dx1/dt, x2'[t] -> dx2/dt, 
    x3'[t] -> dx3/dt} // MatrixForm`

Comment: unfortunately, I also could not factor out dt and dw in those equations, since I would like the coefficients elsewhere when you factor them out. thanks again for those who provide me with some help.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment, xiaofu, but I'm glad that it seems to work. I'm going to copy your code into my answer to make it more complete.

Comment: Hi dskeletov, no problem, please make the answer complete, so that everyone could learn it, besides as for the new question, if you have a system equations as shown below`eqns1 = {dx1/dt == (a + b + c) dt + (e + f) dw, 
   x2/dt == (a1 + a2 + a3) dt + (e1 + e2) dw} // MatrixForm`, how can you extract the a+b+c, a1+a2+a3 and e+f from the eqns1? since I do not want to copy the answer from the output of the eqns1.

Comment: Hi Xiaofu, I've added the answer in the answer (for ease of formatting).

Comment: Hi dskeletov, my questions are fully solved, thanks so much.