# GridLines in ChromaticityPlot

Tags: plotting, grid-lines

How can I place `GridLines` *above* the colored region of a `ChromaticityPlot` (and hence make them visible throughout the plot) without resorting to `Mesh` or drawing explicit lines?  This example shows the default is to place the `GridLines` *behind* the colored area, and is hence unacceptable:

```
ChromaticityPlot["RGB", {"CIE31", .96},
 GridLines -> {Range[0, .8, .1], Range[0, .8, .1]},
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ChromaticityPlot["RGB", {"CIE31", .96}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[0, .8, .1], Range[0, .8, .1]}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange], 
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

**Note:** This and other previously undocumented `Method` suboptions are now documented in [Graphics > Options > Method](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html):

[image]

Note also that, as is true for all `*Plot` and `*Chart` functions, many `Graphics` options accepted by a plot/chart function are not listed in the options section of the function's reference page. This is mentioned under the `Options and Details` sections.

[image]

Comment: Oh my... `GridLinesInFront`... who would have thought!  (It should be added to the WRI documentation for ChromaticityPlot.)  Thanks so much.  ($+1, \checkmark$).

Comment: FYI `GridLinesInFront` is mentionned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/5467)

Comment: This is now documented in [Graphics >> Options >> Method](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html).